# What does information between "@@" means in git dif

Tags: git, diff

When I use git diff command in git I see output like this:

@@ -35,14 +41,12 @@

and can't realize what does it mean. I guess that minus means a row when deletion was made, and + is row with insertion. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A hunk begins with range information and is immediately followed with
>   the line additions, line deletions, and any number of the contextual
>   lines. The range information is surrounded by double-at signs, and
>   combines onto a single line what appears on two lines in the context
>   format (above). The format of the range information line is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> @@ -l,s +l,s @@ optional section heading
> ```
>
> The hunk range information contains two hunk ranges. The range for the
>   hunk of the original file is preceded by a minus symbol, and the range
>   for the new file is preceded by a plus symbol. Each hunk range is of
>   the format l,s where l is the starting line number and s is the number
>   of lines the change hunk applies to for each respective file. In many
>   versions of GNU diff, each range can omit the comma and trailing value
>   s, in which case s defaults to 1. Note that the only really
>   interesting value is the l line number of the first range; all the
>   other values can be computed from the diff.

*Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format*

Comment: So they're just arbitrary delimiters for the range information. They might as well have been `\m/ -l,s +l,s \m/`.